# Incorporate main-site questions into a team

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

I wonder if there is an effective way of incorporating main-site questions into a private team.

Of course, one can always link the question.  And perhaps the license on the main site would allow a simple copy-paste to a private team.

But I imagine that for some questions, a main-site question might be exactly what a team needs, without any need to edit it all.

For example, if an educational team had a question like, "How do I best configure Outlook for teaching a course?" A main-site's answer to a "How do I best configure outlook (in general)" might be just what the team needed -- no need to write or maintain an answer, just link it to the main-site question and be done.

Or maybe just copy-paste the main site question's text with a link, and be done...

Comment: An example a bit more on topic than that would be nice, even if not necessary.

Comment: It's more of a super-user example, true. This just highlights the extensiveness required for the feature to work -- would need to be able to incorporate material from any stack exchange site for it to work, I think!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423176/can-i-save-store-a-public-stack-overflow-question-in-my-private-team